# How do I grouping data in geochart using tooltip column values?

Tags: google-visualization

I am using geoChart to display following data in country Map

I have plotted the  map using State cloumn and TotalSales($) as value Column

Now ,the tooltip displays like this  : ID
                                       TotalSales($_113607.00)

I have following summary data in datatable

[image]

this is my actual data

[image]

Now I have added more columns(City,Brandname) to break data from summary data from first table

The tooltip displays like this : VA
                                     Totalsales($_:34943(City Fairfax(BrandName sony)))- this is wrong

But I want to display the tooltip like this : VA
                         Totalsales($_:7768(City Fairfax(BrandName sony)))  - this is correct

this is my data to display tooltip

[image]

From these, what I got is , Geochart takes only last row for display tooltip,but I want to display particular brand's Totalsales i.e sony -7768$

How do I do this?

Comment: you need to include the code you are using to generate the chart. Obviously you are lumping some columns together, as if you were actually displaying just state and sales, the column would be indicated as the state name (in the case above, "VA" or "CA" or "MN").

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data in geo chart using the [CategoryFilter Control](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#categoryfilter_control). You can group data in this way.

```
        var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'BrandName',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 3, // filter by brand name
            ui: {
                caption: 'Choose a brand',
                sortValues: true,
                allowNone: true,
                allowMultiple: false,
                allowTyping: true
            }
        },  
        state: 
        {
        selectedValues: ['Samsung']
    }
    });
```

Here is the working sample [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-categorize-the-tool-tip-content-using-control-wrapper/). Hope this will help you.